# Xdb Migration tool - The item Database verification log could not be converted into a database verification log object

Tags: xdb, mongodb, migration

I am working on `Analytics DB migration` from MongoDB to Connect using `Sitecore_xDB_Data_Migration_Tool 5.0.0` for `Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 10.x`.

I followed installation guide from below url https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_xDB_Data_Migration_Tool/5x/xDB_Data_Migration_Tool_500.aspx.

I deployed the `verification database in SQL` and tried installing the xDB Data Migration Tool for the Data Exchange Framework package in Sitecore 10.x.

I have configured the verification database in the Connection string as mentioned below.

```
<add name="def.Verification" connectionString="data source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.DataExchange.Verification;Integrated Security=SSPI;persist security info=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am not sure if this is correct since when I try to run the `Database Verification Log` (`sitecore/system/Settings/Data Exchange/Framework/Verification Log/Database Verification Log`) I get the below error.

[image]

Can anyone help with this?

Thank you

Comment: On the PipeLine Batches item, can you check the Enable Verification check box?

Comment: I have enabled it already but still, I get the error. Is the entry in the connection string right?

Comment: No this the field in the PipeLine Batches Item as a checkbox.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it. Still I see the error.